# Host GPG / PGP keys online?

Tags: email, gpg

Is there any way for me to setup my GPG key online so that they could be used to verify my signature?

I mean, I own "thezombie.net", so I might as well host my key there, no?

And locally, what do I need? I upload the public key, and locally must have both the private and public ones, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you uploaded your key to one of the public [keyservers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_server_(cryptographic))?

You can upload your public key at any location that is convent for the people you will be communicating to retrieve it.

Yes, always keep your private key private.  Nobody else should every be given access to your private key or the pass-phrase you used to encrypt it.